# how to send multiple http2 requests over the same connection with libcurl

Tags: libcurl, http2

I'm using https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/http2-download.html to send mulitple http2 requests to a demo http server. This server is based on spring webflux. To verify if libcurl can send http2 requests concurrently, the server will delay 10 seconds before return response. In this way, I hope to observe that the server will receive multiple http2 requests at almost the same time **over the same connection**, after 10 seconds, the client will receive responses.

However,I noticed that the server received the requests sequentially. It seems that the client doesn't send the next request before geting the response of previous request.

Here is the log of server, the requests arrived every 10 seconds.

2021-05-07 17:14:57.514  INFO 31352 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] i.g.h.mongo.controller.PostController    : Call get 609343a24b79c21c4431a2b1

2021-05-07 17:15:07.532  INFO 31352 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] i.g.h.mongo.controller.PostController    : Call get 609343a24b79c21c4431a2b1

2021-05-07 17:15:17.541  INFO 31352 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] i.g.h.mongo.controller.PostController    : Call get 609343a24b79c21c4431a2b1

Any guys can help figure out my mistakes? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For me,

```
curl -v --http2 --parallel --config urls.txt
```

did exactly what you need, where urls.txt was like

```
url = "localhost:8080/health"
url = "localhost:8080/health"
```

the result was that at first, curl sent first request via HTTP/1.1, received 101 upgrade to http/2, immediately sent the second request without waiting for response, and then received two times 200 response in succession.

Note: `-v` is added for verbosity to validate it works as expected. You don't need it other than for printing the underlying protocol conversation.